# How can be that a destructor is called but no constuctor before that?

Tags: c++, oop, destructor, copy-constructor, virtual-destructor

I am currently learning the object oriented feature of c++. I wrote a piece of code to test how inheritance and polymorphism works.
Here is a part of the code:

```
    class Person
{
    public:
    Person()
    {
        cout << "Person constructed\n";
    }

    virtual void introduce()
    {
        cout << "hi from person" << endl;
    }

    ~Person()
    {
        cout << "Person destructed\n";
    }
};

class Student : public Person 
{
    public:
    Student()
    {
        cout << "Student constructed\n";
    }

    void introduce()
    {
        cout << "hi from student" << endl;
    }

    ~Student()
    {
        cout << "Student destructed\n";
    }
};

class Farmer : public Person 
{
    public:
    Farmer()
    {
        cout << "Farmer constructed\n";
    }

    void introduce()
    {
        cout << "hi from farmer" << endl;
    }

    ~Farmer()
    {
        cout << "Farmer destructed\n";
    }
};

class SJW : public Student
{
    public:
    SJW()
    {
        cout << "SJW constructed\n";
    }

    ~SJW()
    {
        cout << "SJW destructed\n";
    }
};

void whoisthis3(Person object)
{
    object.introduce();
}

int main()
{
    Student mark;
    SJW bigred;
    Farmer max;

    cout << endl;

    whoisthis3(mark);
    whoisthis3(max);
    whoisthis3(bigred);

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output that it produces:

```
Person constructed
Student constructed
Person constructed
Student constructed
SJW constructed
Person constructed
Farmer constructed

hi from person
Person destructed
hi from person
Person destructed
hi from person
Person destructed

Farmer destructed
Person destructed
SJW destructed
Student destructed
Person destructed
Student destructed
Person destructed
```

These derived classes are constructed and destructed at the beginning and at the end as expected. But how can be that when the whoisthis3 method executes, a Person destructor is called? What is happenning there?

Comment: Copy constructor is called, which doesn't print anything since it's just the default.

Comment: I don't really understand this yet. What is the need for a copy constructor there?

Comment: Change the whoisthis3 routine to: `void whoisthis3(Person& object)`

Comment: I know, there are 3 variants of that function, one of them is what you mentioned. I did not include the other ones here though.

Comment: Then implement a copy constructor and assignment operator for your classes

Comment: @Julius_Evola, if you pass-by-copy (as your function is), then it will call the copy constructor. Generally, when passing into functions, pass-by-reference is preferred, as it does not make a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void whoisthis3(Person object)
{
    object.introduce();
}
```

This function accepts its `object` parameter by value.  That means that a new `Person` object is created as a copy of the object that you pass to `whoisthis3`.  Since you haven't explicitly defined `Person`'s copy constructor, this uses the default copy constructor generated by the compiler.  When function ends, its `object` parameter is destroyed, and you see the statement printed by its destructor.

---

Note that, as you've observed, `whoisthis3` will always call `Person::introduce` since `object` is a `Person`, not any type derived from it.  This is commonly referred to as [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: Okay, so the objects are treated the same way as variables. But why copy constructors? The function could just invoke the normal constructor.

Comment: @Julius_Evola Because it needs to make a copy of the object.  To do that you need access to the object being copied.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following simple program:

```
struct A 
{
    A() { std::cout << "construct A\n";  }
    ~A() { std::cout << "destruct A\n";  }  
};

int main()
{
  A a;
}
```

This prints:

```
constructs A
destructs A
```

as expected.

Now let's add a simple function:

```
void f(A a) {}
```

and call it:

```
int main()
{
  A a;
  f(a);
}
```

and we see:

```
construct A
destruct A
destruct A
```

Now where did that extra `destruct A` come from? and where is the corresponding `construct A`? The answer is, when you call `f`, the default copy constructor is invoked. If you print stuff in the copy-constructor, like this:

```
A(A const&) { std::cout << "copy-construct A\n"; }
```

then you get the output:

```
construct A
copy-construct A
destruct A
destruct A
```

which shows that indeed, 2 objects have been constructed, and then both are destroyed.

On the other hand, if `f` takes the argument by reference like this:

```
void f(A& a) {}
```

then the copy-constructor is not called (since no copy is made), and the output would be:

```
construct A
destruct A
```

Comment: Ahh, now I realized that actually the same thing happens with these objects as with plain old variables. This makes total sense now.

Comment: Good, I'm glad you understand it now :)

Comment: But why the compiler have this feature? Why it isnt' invoking the normal constructor then?

Comment: Because it's often useful to create an object from another object of the same type. This feature lets you do that easily.

Comment: @Julius_Evola • The copy constructor is a normal constructor.  (Even if is synthesized for you by the compiler.)